# How to calculate the diskspace used by MySQL table from column datatypes and number of rows?

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL table with more than a 3 billion rows hosted on Google Cloud SQL.

I wish to understand how the total size on disk can be explained from the column data-types, number of rows and the indexes.

I was hoping that it would be something like

```
size_of_table_in_bytes = num_rows * [ Sum over i {bytes_for_datatype_of_column(i))}
                                    + Sum over j  {Bytes_for_index(j)} ]
```

But I end up with incorrect disk-size than how much my database size shows.

Using bytes per datatype on

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

and additional bytes in InnoDB header and indexes from

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html#innodb-compact-row-format-characteristics

Here is my understanding of bytes occupied by header, each column and each index

```
TABLE `depth` (
Bytes| Column/Header/Index
    2| variable length header Ceil(num columns/8) = Ceil (10/8)
    5| Fixed Length Header
    3|`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    7|`receive_time` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    8|`instrument_token` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    1|`level `tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    2|`bid_count` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    8|`bid_size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    4|`bid_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    4|`ask_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    8|`ask_size` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    2|`ask_count` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    6|KEY `date_time_sym (`date`,`receive_time`,`instrument_token`),
    6|KEY `date_sym_time (`date`,`instrument_token`,`receive_time`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

which totals to 72 bytes.

But as per SHOW TABLE STATUS, Avg_row_length = 79.

**Question 1: Where am I getting the number of bytes per row wrong?**

I am reasonably sure that there are no nulls in my data.

Assuming, I am making some mistake in counting bytes, and using 79 bytes per row
and counting rows using `SELECT COUNT(*)` as `3,017,513,240`:

```
size_of_table_in_bytes = 79*3,017,513,240 = 238,383,545,960
```

Another way to get the size is to use MySQL query

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS from mktdata where Name = "depth";
```

Here I get a table output with one row, with value of a few important fields as:

```
Name: depth
Engine:InnoDB
Version:10
Row_format:Dynamic
Rows: 1,72,08,21,447 
Avg_row_length: 78
Index_length: 1,83,90,03,07,456
Data_length:  1,35,24,53,32,480
```

At first I was alarmed, how `Rows` is 1.7 Billion instead of 3.01 Billion, but I found this in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html)

> - Rows
>
> > The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the exact 
> >     count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40 to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count.

So, 3.01 Billion seems right for number of rows, and therefore I expect table size to be 238 GB.

But then, if I add up, `Data_length` and `Index_length`, I get `319,145,639,936`

**Question 2: Why do I get 319 GB by one method and 238 GB as another. Which one is right if any?**

Moreover the overall size shown for the SQL database by Google Cloud SQL Console is 742 GB. The only other table I have, `trade`, has exactly 1/5th the number of rows of `depth` and 5 columns. It's size by summing `Data_length` and `Index_length` is 57 GB. If I add both the table sizes I get 376 GB.

**Question 3: 742 GB seems roughly twice of 376 GB (actually 752). Could this be because of the back-up? I know Google Cloud SQL does an automatic back-up once a day?**

Because of plausibility of Question 3 above, I got a doubt that my simple method of `size = num_rows*num_bytes_per_row` is wrong! This is really troubling me, and will appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: You are using `MySQL` not `MS SQL Server`, please remove `SQL-Server` tag

Comment: Do you have binary logs enabled? If yes you have to account for their size as well.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked log_bin = ON. How to check its size?

Comment: `SHOW BINARY LOGS;`

Comment: I get a table with Log_name,File_size as column. Sum of File_size across 872 rows is 85,661,147,002. This explains 85 GB of disk-space?

Answer (score 0):

- There is more overhead than you mentioned.  20 bytes/row *might* be *close*.
- Don't trust `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for giving "Rows", use `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`  Notice how it was off by nearly a factor of 2.
- Compute the other way: 135245332480 / 3017513240 = 45 bytes.
- From 45 bytes, I deduce that a lot of the cells are NULL?
- Each column in each row has 1- or 2-byte overhead.
- The `ROW_FORMAT` matters.
- `TEXT` and `BLOB` (etc) have radically different rules than simple datatypes.
- The indexes take a lot more than the 6 bytes you mentioned (see your [other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47837332/edit)).
- BTree structure has some overhead.  When loaded in order, 15/16 of each block is filled (that is mentioned somewhere in the docs).  After churn, the range can easily be 50-100% is filled; a BTree gravitates to 69% full (hence the 1.45 in the other posting).

Reserving an equal amount of space for backup...

- I don't know if that is what they are doing.
- If they use mysqldump (or similar), it is not a safe formula -- the *text* dump of the database could be significantly larger or smaller.
- If they use LVM, then they have room for a full binary dump.  But that does not make sense because of COW.
- (So, I give up on Q3.)

Could the Cloud service be doing some kind of compression?

Comment: Disk usage does not include backups (they are stored separately). The rest of the disk usage likely comes from binary logs as I mentioned in a previous comment.

Comment: ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic. There are no `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns. Yes index thing I realized later. There can't be so many nulls. I'll count.

Comment: Vadim, Google Cloud provides a visual interface, where it is showing 750+ GB in my database. I'll need to ask them if it includes back-ups. Thanks for your log comment, 85 GB is explained.

Comment: I work on Google Cloud. As I mentioned in my first comment, the disk usage displayed does not contain anything related to backups.